# Visual Studio run Docker-enabled project without docker in debug-mode

Tags: visual-studio, docker, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and have added Docker-support for my .NET Core-project. Everything works fine when I'm deploying it, but because of domain-limitations I cannot run Docker locally. Is there any  way to run/debug a project without using Docker locally when docker support has been added?

My **.csproj** looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ....
```

And my **launchSettings.json**:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "SomeProject": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same exact question. (You worded it very consicely.) I can run docker locally. But I just want to know if there is a simple Visual Studio option to re-build and debug outside of a container once the Dockerfile is present. What I discovered is that if you 'Clean' the build and comment out the `Docker` section in _launchSetting.json_, (using `//`)you can run/debug in the normal console. But i don't know if there is an easier way.

Comment: However, after messing with _launchSettings.json_ I found I now had the opposite problem. I could not get it to debug in a container without deleting the Dockerfile, the launchSettings.json, the Containers.Tools.Targets package, removing all images, and re-adding container support...

Comment: @mdisibio yes, I did the exact same thing. But it was very messy, and I believe it should be a simpler way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can! If you select the little debug menu arrow (to the right of the start debugging button shown in the image) you can select whichever debug setup works best for you.

If you have multiple startup projects you'll have to set each one as the sole startup project in turn to access this menu, then set up your multiple startup projects again.

[image: Debug menu]